# Ngx-translate: Change path to localization files

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

In `ngx-translate` library, is there a way how to change the path where `TranslateService` looks for localization files (`en-GB` etc.)? The default one is `src/assets/i18n/[lang].json`.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/switch-multiple-languages-i18n-using-ngx-translate-in-angular-12/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can change the path to the translation files by creating a loader in your app.module.ts, as described in the documentation:

https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#configuration

i.e:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {AppComponent} from './app';
   
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: httpTranslateLoader,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

// Set the path here
export function httpTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
        return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/locales/', '.json');
}
```

I would suggest using the environments to set the locales path:

```
export function httpTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, environment.languageFilesPath, '.json');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed this point in documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i did a little digging and realize that ngx-translate uses the browser's default naming convention. If you look at [ngx-translate/core/src/lib/translate.service.ts](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/3a4c7ee9e56a86f72a42dd3590122b0db7667779/projects/ngx-translate/core/src/lib/translate.service.ts) **Line 506**

So if u want to change it's naming conversion you will have to do a lot of editing to the original ngx-translate module.

I will recommend you to continue using it's recommended naming convention. Or write a script to adopt to it's naming convention as the module is using the name convention of browsers.

I hope this will help you, good luck.

Comment: Well, in my ```angular.json``` there is no mention about ```i18n``` (maybe and need to create some extra node?) and ```TranslateService``` is not my service, it is a part of ```ngx-translate``` library. Regarding ```app.module``` I supplemented my question.